# NetworkManager - WiFi connection breaks soon after connecting

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, networkmanager

NetworkManager - WiFi connection breaks soon after connecting

Hey,

**Question and problem description:**

Until yesterday, my home WiFi works perfectly. And now, very soon (seconds to minutes) after establishing the WiFi connection, I loose the network (`ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable`).

To be more precise, when booting my laptop and automatically logging into my WiFi I can establish a connection. I also can use access the Web via Chrome/Firefox for a little time.

This is ping's output:

```
user@laptop ~ $ ping www.google.at
PING www.google.at (216.58.213.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ham02s15-in-f195.1e100.net (216.58.213.195): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=45.7 ms
64 bytes from ham02s15-in-f195.1e100.net (216.58.213.195): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=35.3 ms
64 bytes from ham02s15-in-f195.1e100.net (216.58.213.195): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=34.0 ms
```

After several seconds the latency is getting very high ...

```
64 bytes from ham02s15-in-f195.1e100.net (216.58.213.195): icmp_seq=40 ttl=52 time=794 ms
64 bytes from ham02s15-in-f195.1e100.net (216.58.213.195): icmp_seq=41 ttl=52 time=804 ms
```

... and ping's output changes to

```
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable 
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
```

My home's WiFi works also fine on smartphones as well as using the a direct connection to the router via a ethernet cable.

**What had probably changed?**

Yesterday I logged in to a for my laptop unknown WiFi (my university's one) and since then my home's WiFi has the problem I described before. I guess that, by using the external WiFi some NetworkManager setting had changed?

**My setup**

1. Linux Mint 17
2. NetworkManager 0.9.8.8
3. Laptop HP625

**Additional infos**

ifconfig's output for my wifi

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:2a:82:a0:8e:1f  
          inet addr:192.168.0.13  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e22a:82ff:fea0:8e1f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13281 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12084 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14711000 (14.7 MB)  TX bytes:2746665 (2.7 MB)
```

Thanks in advance for any help,
Jürgen

Comment: Have you tired with some other device?  Maybe your phone with university's wifi and home wifi

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

I deleted the content of the following directory

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

rebooted, and than logged into my home's WiFi once more, and then it worked!

What exactly the problem was, I don't know. It's a little bit weird, that it now worked, because I had deleted all the properties of the home's WiFi as well as the one of the university's (previously unknown to my laptop) WiFi via the NetworkManager-GUI.